# Mudar a versão do TLS em envio PHP

Tags: php, ssl

Meu envio esta retornando esse erro ...

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead…): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 TLS 1.1 or higher required in /home/storage/9/8e/3d/teste1124/public_html/tpl/site.php on line 124

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(    
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => $content,
    )
));

$result = file_get_contents('https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8', null, $context);
```

> E parece que a solicitação file_get_contents está usando TLS 1.0, que parou de ser suportado pelo salesforce...

Obs 01 ... A line 124 do erro, no cód é a linha $result = file_get_contents , acima.

> MONTEI ASSIM, para eu poder testar ................................................................................

```
$context = stream_context_create([array(
     'http' => array(                                                       
         'method'  => 'POST',
         'content' => $content,
     ),
     'ssl' => [
          'crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_1_CLIENT |
                             STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT,
     ],
)]);

$result = file_get_contents('https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8', false, $context);
```

> ERRO === Warning: stream_context_create(): options should have the form ["wrappername"]["optionname"] = $value in /home/storage/9/8e/3d/teste1124/public_html/tpl/index.php on line 126

Obs 02 ... A line 126 === )]);  do cód. acima.

> **Como posso corrigir e ajustar corretamente este meu envio ?**
>   **Estou montando errado o envio ou o que será ?**

Comment: Olá Paulo, qual a versão do PHP que esta usando e qual é o seu sistema operacional da hospedagem?

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento  A versão do servidor é PHP Version 5.4.45 & Linux

Comment: entendo, é que se fosse 5.6 algumas coisas talvez seriam diferentes (em questão do SSL), mas sendo 5.4 ou 5.5 dá pra resolver mais facilmente. Já vou elaborar uma resposta

Comment: Isso, só estou instalando o PHP5.4 aqui pra criar um exemplo funcional pra ti, minha internet é lenta e eu só tenho o PHP7.1 que é diferente do 5.4. Salvei sua pergunta nos favoritos pra não me esquecer, até breve.

Comment: @PauloMaia há algum motivo especifico que lhe impede de usar o cURL? Acredito que seria bem mais fácil, uma vez que bastaria usar `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION`.

Comment: Isso não vai funcioanr, afinal `3` não é o TLS 1.1. Mude para `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2`, de forma a ficar `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);`

Comment: Então, especificar o `3` é o mesmo que a versão SSLv3. O SSLv3 é anterior ao TLS 1.1. O site exige que use TLS 1.1 ou superior, portanto use o `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2` ou `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1`. Se quiser realmente usar números, ao invés das constantes, use `5` ou `6`. Mas, não use `3`....

Comment: Sem Resposta , Alguém  ?